# Python RTMidi misses Start MIDI message

Tags: midi

New issue on my Rpi 3b+ :(
I'm using the RTMidi Python lib to monitor incoming midi messages from a midi keyboard, plugged using USB.
I can see all incoming messages (notes, stop, continue..).
But not the "Start" ones.
This is really strange because on my mac laptop I've got no problem seeing all the messages using the exact same code:

```
midi_in = rtmidi.MidiIn()
midi_in.open_port(1)

while True:
    message= midi_in.get_message()
    if message:
        print message[0]
```

If anyone has a hint regarding this it would awesome!! 
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you see all messages with `aseqdump`?

Comment: Hey! Thanks just tried it and it works, I receive all the midi messages including the start one. So the issue is in the RTMidi midi_in.get_message() .. Any idea why ?

Comment: I see no reason why the start message would be handled differently.

Comment: Yeah super weird.. 
Running some extensive tests I actually do get the start message sometimes, like once every 10 tries